# Calling a Base Method Template Subclass

Tags: c++, templates

I had a problem, which I eventually reduced down to this simple example:

```
template <int dimensions> class Base {
    protected:
        Base(void) {}
    public:
        virtual ~Base(void) {}

        void base_method(void) {}
};
template <int dimensions> class MyClass : public Base<dimensions> {
    public:
        MyClass(void) : Base<dimensions>() {
            base_method();
        }
        ~MyClass(void) {}
};
```

This compiles fine on MSVC 2010, but fails with g++ 4.6:

```
main2.cpp: In constructor âMyClass<dimensions>::MyClass()â:
main2.cpp:12:16: error: there are no arguments to âbase_methodâ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of âbase_methodâ must be available [-fpermissive]
main2.cpp:12:16: note: (if you use â-fpermissiveâ, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

What's going on?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do:

```
this->base_method();
```

or

```
Base<dimension>::base_method();
```

Compilers generally will not consider methods in templated base class for function resolution.

Comment: (Note that the first allows virtual overriding and the second does not.)

Comment: "Compilers generally will not consider methods in templated base class for function resolution." interesting.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly call `Base<dimensions>::base_method()`.